# webpack does not recognize file-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a project in react with webpack and add an image, I added the file-loader and the image and gave the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/images/image.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./src/pages/Home/index.js 26:0-52
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js
```

my webpack looks like this:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,  
    use: [
      'file-loader'
      ]
  }
```

If I remove the file-loader the error continues, then the problem is that it does not recognize the file-loader, but I can not resolve.

I load the image like this, but I've tried it in other ways and the error is always the same:

```
import imgHome from "../../assets/images/image.png"
```

Installed Packages:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"css-loader": "^2.0.0",
"file-loader": "^3.0.1",
"flow-bin": "^0.86.0",
"flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"style-loader": "^0.23.1",
"webpack": "^4.26.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `package.json` and see if there is `file-loader`.

If not, you may need to install it by:

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

Try this:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {},
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: I installed, I already tried the url-loader too and the same error appears